# Yii2: Сложные relation и dataprovider. Поможете?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

Репит вопроса на  тостере https://toster.ru/q/207608

Итак. Есть соц сеть. Куча таблиц и зависимостей. Вот часть из них.
Пользователь может быть владельцем клуба (club.owner_id) и может состоять в клубах (users_clubs) - many_many:

[image]

Каждый пользователь генерирует события. События привязаны только к пользователю. Необходимо сделать вывод в gridview список событий в клубе. То есть выводить события всех пользователей относящихся к конкретному клубу.

Набросал вот такой sql:

```
            SELECT
                e.id, e. c.club_id, u.name
            FROM
                events AS e
                JOIN user AS u
                    ON e.owner_id = u.id
                JOIN users_clubs AS uc
                    ON uc.user_id = u.id
                JOIN clubs AS c
                    ON c.id = uc.club_id
            WHERE
                c.id = :club_id
```

Имеются модели:
**User**:

```
public function getClubs(){
    return $this->hasMany(Club::className(), ['id'=>'club_id'])
        ->viaTable('users_clubs', ['user_id'=>'id']);
}
```

**Event**:

```
public function getOwner(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id'=>'owner_id']);
}
```

**Club**:

```
public function getMembers($count = 100){
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id'=>'user_id'])
        ->limit($count)
        ->viaTable('users_clubs', ['club_id'=>'id'], function($query){
            $query->where(['status'=>User::STATUS_CLUB_JOINED_APPROVED]);
        });
}
```

**Search модели Event**:

```
public function search($params){
    $query = Event::find(); // я так понимаю вся движуха должна быть здесь или вынесена в EventQuery впоследствии
    $this->scenario = 'search';

    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query'=>$query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['id' => $this->id]);


    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Есть ли у кого время и возможность помочь с вопросом?
Благодарю.

Comment: typo: `e.id, e. c.club_id, u.name`?

Comment: e.id - event.id
c.club_id - club.id
u.name = user.name

c. - copy/paste bug ) sorry